# Sending a Text Message from a WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, sms

One of the requests from my product owner is to have some of our company cell phones get a text message if a specific event occurs.

I can easily capture the event in my WCF services.  But I am not really sure where to go for the text message part.  Is this something I need to subscribe to a service for.  Is there a way to just do it free?  Do I have to go with a carrier?

I am using C#, .NET 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com) or [Tropo](http://www.tropo.com) - both SMS gateways you can interact with programatically.

Comment: If you have questions about Twilio, I'm happy to answer them: jsheehan@twilio.com. Also, I have a C# wrapper library that makes sending from .NET really easy: http://github.com/johnsheehan/TwilioApi

Answer (score 0):

Lots of sms-services on the internet. For my latest project at work I had to use [smsextrapro](http://www.smsextrapro.com/) but I don't know the rates for that.

I send an email to them with the appropriate details + the message and they do the rest. Pretty easy and straight forward.

Just google around and compare some of the services to see what suits you and your client best.

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on where you are trying to send SMS's.. For example, here in Canada, most providers have the ability to send an [SMS via an email address hosted for each phone user](http://www.theblog.ca/free-sms-canada). The catch is that you need to know which telco the user's phone number maps to.